# Python - Pandas - String Replacement with regex | (OR)

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I've got 2 Dataframes :

```
df_bisID = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ID1#ID2', 'ID3#ID4'],
                         'B': ['ID5#ID6', 'ID7#ID8'],
                         'C': ['ID9#ID10', 'ID11#ID12'],
                         'D': ['ID13#ID14', 'ID15#ID16']})

    A       B       C           D
0   ID1#ID2 ID5#ID6 ID9#ID10    ID13#ID14
1   ID3#ID4 ID7#ID8 ID11#ID12   ID15#ID16


df_eliminateID = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ID1', 'ID3', 'ID9', 'ID11'],
                               'B': ['ID5', 'ID7', 'ID13', 'ID15']})

    A    B
0   ID1  ID5
1   ID3  ID7
2   ID9  ID13
3   ID11 ID15
```

The IDs are complicated, with alphanumerics, and unique  ('xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxx'+ facultative suffix '-xxx-xxx'). I propose an example with simplified IDs.

In df_bisID I need to get rid of one of both ID and #, in each column, where it's respectively contained in columns A or B in df_eliminateID.

So I want to replace 'ID1#ID2' by 'ID2' and 'ID9#ID10' by 'ID10', etc.

Note that it also could be 'ID2#ID1' instead of 'ID1#ID2' and it's complicating the replacement conditions, that's also the cause of this question string replacement.

A logical solution to my problem is :

```
for i in df_eliminateID['A']:
    df_bisID.replace(i+'#|#'+i, '')
for i in df_eliminateID['B']:
    df_bisID.replace(i+'#|#'+i, '')
```

But at the end, my df_bisID is empty, that's why I ask your help with the use of | regex in my string replacement, I want to replace IDX# or #IDX by '' to conserve only one of the IDs.
The OR is | in regex, maybe I didn't used it the right way (is there an exclusif or in regex ?)

In advance, thanks for your help.

**EDIT: A SOLUTION FOUND !**

I had to replace some '_' into '-' previously in my dataframe with

```
df.replace('_', '-', regex=True)
```

If regex=False, it doesn't work, I do not understand exactly why (if somebody could explain it to me it would be really cool, I searched in the docs but with no gains in terms of comprehension)

So I decided to test if it would work on this problem to :

```
dfbis = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ID1#ID2', 'ID3#ID4'],
                      'B': ['ID5#ID6', 'ID7#ID8'],
                      'C': ['ID9#ID20', 'ID21#ID22'],
                      'D': ['ID23#ID24', 'ID25#ID26']})
    A       B       C           D
0   ID1#ID2 ID5#ID6 ID9#ID20  ID23#ID24
1   ID3#ID4 ID7#ID8 ID21#ID22 ID25#ID26

dfdetermine = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ID1', 'ID3', 'ID20', 'ID22'],
                            'B': ['ID5', 'ID7', 'ID23', 'ID25']})

    A    B
0   ID1  ID5
1   ID3  ID7
2   ID20 ID23
3   ID22 ID25

for i in dfdetermine['A'], dfdetermine['B']:
    print(i)
    dfbis = dfbis.replace(i+'#', '', regex=True).replace('#'+i, '', regex=True)

dfbis

    A   B   C    D
0   ID2 ID6 ID9  ID24
1   ID4 ID8 ID21 ID26
```

I changed the ID10+ into ID20+, if not the ID1 test was perturbing the result.

Also, I found something about string replacement timing that inspired me to put appart the IDX# and #IDX replacement into 2 calls to df.replace : https://qastack.fr/programming/3411771/best-way-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string

Do you think my program could be optimised ?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend checking out the string ops available to pandas objects, especially the [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) function, which I think is exactly what you want here:

```
for i in df_eliminateID['A']:    
    df_bisID = df_bisID.str.replace(f'{i}#|#{i}', '')
for i in df_eliminateID['B']:
    df_bisID = df_bisID.str.replace(f'{i}#|#{i}', '')
```

Comment: `str.replace` is a pd.Series function, the equivalent for an entire DataFrame is `replace` which I'm already using but not successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can rework your columns index, `stack`, remove the trailing part of the string and `unstack`:

```
(df_bisID.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1],
                                               df_bisID.columns[:2]]),
                   axis=1)
         .stack(level=[0,1])
         .str.split('#').str[0]
         .unstack()
         .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

output:

```
      A     B
0   ID1   ID5
1   ID9  ID13
2   ID3   ID7
3  ID11  ID15
```